# Why is '[0] so commonly (and recently) appended to query strings?

Tags: websecurity, web-application-firewall, nwebsec

I use a WAF that monitors suspicious query string and form POST values. Over the last several months I've noticed a dramatic uptick in query strings that have this sequence of 4 characters appended to the usual (i.e. 'normal') values:

'[0]

Why is this so common? I know why stuff like SQL injection attempts and JS snippets appear all the time, but is this string a known attack vector?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the URLs which has been logged, that include this `[0]` sequence.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is really a web server question, for [webmasters.se].